# css floating problem: how to get a left float to wrap around a right float

Tags: css

have a box that displays images wrapped in a div from a database 4 across x 4 high. The image are floating to the left so they self wrap. But I want to add an object (a div) to the top right and have the images wrap around (so only 3 in the first row, then 4 every row after). I've tried using float right, absolute, relative and nothing gets it to display correctly.

Any tips?

EDIT (CODE):

I add the div first then the images, what happens is that the div pushes the image that would otherwise be in the 4th spot down out of the way, doesn't wrap it.

This is my goal:

```
| Image(in div)  Image(in div)   Image(in div)    Div   |
| Image(in div)  Image(in div)   Image(in div)    Image(in div) |
| Image(in div)  Image(in div)   Image(in div)    Image(in div) |
| Image(in div)  Image(in div)   Image(in div)    Image(in div) |
```

Images:

```
position:relative;
float:left;
height:200px;
width:200px;
```

Div:

```
position:relative;
float:right;
height:200px;
width:200px;
```

Comment: You should include sample code :)

Comment: And did you try the `clear` property? http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_clear.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply place the `div` in front of all the images, then float it to the right:

```
#right {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
}
```

with this HTML:

```
<div id="right">
    Some text, content. </div>

<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
[...]
```

Usually there isn't a need to float the `img` elements here, since they are inline elements already. See this working live here: http://jsfiddle.net/wQfAc/

Comment: Thing is they are images wrapped in a div (for captions) so how would I make the Image-div's inline? (display:inline doesn't work)

Comment: @John You can float the wrapper div elements, and float them too - http://jsfiddle.net/wQfAc/1/

Comment: still not working for me in practice but I'll figure it out, since it obviously worked for you. thx

Answer (score 0):

tough to say without looking at your html and css, but as a general tip have you tried rendering the div you are floating right first in your HTML before all the images?